# What Transformation values to calculate for scale and translate if you want to zoom

Tags: d3.js

Im looking at this example which shows how one can use the zoom functionality to zoom in a specified domain range

https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/431a331294d2b5ddd33f947cf4c81319

Im confused about this part:

```
var d0 = new Date(2003, 0, 1),
    d1 = new Date(2004, 0, 1);

// Gratuitous intro zoom!
svg.call(zoom).transition()
      .duration(1500)
      .call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity
          .scale(width / (x(d1) - x(d0))) // I think this is to caulcuate k which is the zoom factor
          .translate(-x(d0), 0)); // but what is this?
```

I'm having trouble understanding the calculations that are done. Correct me if my assumptions are wrong

`d3.zoomIdentity` This is a transformation that does nothing when applied.

`.scale(width / (x(d1) - x(d0)))` This is to calculate how much scale to apply by calculating the ratio between the `width` and the pixel difference between the two data points `d0` and `d1`

`.translate(-x(d0), 0))` I don't understand this part. Why is `x(d0)` negated and how does the `x` coordinate of `d(0)` relate to how much translation need to be applied?

Comment: https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom/blob/master/src/zoom.js

Comment: @RobertHarvey I did see that but I don't understand the calculation in the given context. for eg. why is `x(d0)` negated?

Comment: Perhaps you can make your question more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The translate value is aligning the graph so that `x(d0)` is the leftmost x value visible in the plot area. This ensures the visible portion of the plot area extends from `d0` through `d1` (the visible subdomain). If our full domain for the x scale has a minimum of 0, then `x(0)` will be shifted left (negative shift) `x(d0)` pixels.

I'll use a snippet to demonstrate:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 10, right: 50, bottom: 70, left: 200},
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Scale for Data:
var x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([0, width])
  .domain([0,20]);
  
// Scale for Zoom:
var xZoom = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([0,width])
  .domain([0,width]);
  
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(5);
var xZoomAxis = d3.axisBottom(xZoom);

var zoom = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, 32])
    .translateExtent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
    .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);
    
var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// plot area
g.append("rect")
  .attr("width",width)
  .attr("height",height)
  .attr("fill","url(#stripes)");
  
g.append("text")
  .attr("x",width/2)
  .attr("y",height/2)
  .style("text-anchor","middle")
  .text("plot area");
  
g.append("line")
  .attr("y1",0)
  .attr("y2",height)
  .attr("stroke-width",1)
  .attr("stroke","black");

// zoomed plot area:
var rect = g.append("rect")
  .attr("width",width)
  .attr("height",height)
  .attr("fill","lightgrey")
  .attr("opacity",0.4);
  
// Axis for plot:
g.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);
  
// Axis for zoom:
g.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis axis-zoom-x")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,"+(height+30)+")")
  .call(xZoomAxis);  
  
var text = g.append("text")
  .attr("y", height+60)
  .attr("text-anchor","middle")
  .text("zoom units")
  .attr("x",width/2);
  
// Gratuitous intro zoom:   
var d1 = 18;
var d0 = 8;

svg.call(zoom).transition()
 .duration(2000)
 .call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity
 .scale(width / (x(d1) - x(d0)))
 .translate(-x(d0), 0));


function zoomed() {
  var t = d3.event.transform, xt = t.rescaleX(x);
  xZoom.range([xt(0),xt(20)]);
  g.select(".axis--x").call(xAxis.scale(xt));
  g.select(".axis-zoom-x").call(xZoomAxis.scale(xZoom));
  rect.attr("x", xt(0));
  rect.attr("width", xt(20) - xt(0));
  text.attr("x", xt(10));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="400" height="180">
<defs>
  <pattern id="stripes" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="8" height="8" patternTransform="rotate(45 0 0)">
  <rect width="3" height="8" fill="orange"></rect>
</pattern>
</defs>

</svg>
```

*Snippet Explanation:*

- Plot area: orange stripes
- Full scaled extent of data: grey box.
- Left hand side of plot area is x=0 (pixels) for the parent `g` that holds everything.

As we zoom in the bounds of our data exceeds the plot area. We want to show a specific subdomain of our data. We achieve part of that with the scale (as you correctly deduce) but the other portion is with the translate: we push values less than the lowest value of our x subdomain to the left. By pushing the entire graph left by an amount equal to `x(d0)`, `x(d0)` appears as the leftmost coordinate of the plot area.

Comment: That perfectly explains it! Thank you